# Confusion between もらいます and くれます when used as a post-fix to te-form verbs

Tags: て-form, causation, giving-and-receiving

I was at Japanese class today and I heard these phrases while I was listening to chokai:

休んでくれますか (Can you give me the favour of resting for today)
休ませてもらいませんか (Can you let me rest for today?)
休んでもらいますか (Can I receive the favour of resting for today?)

From my understanding, these phrases mean the same thing (Translation as per my understanding as of above). However, I was told by my japanese teacher that they all mean different things but I could not understand his explanation on why they were different. Can anyone explain why they are different in all 3 cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- 休んでくれま**せんか** is more like **won't you** rest?
- 休ませてもら**え**ますか is like **could you** let me rest?
- 休んでもら**え**ますか is like **could I** have **you** take the day off?

くれる is used when something is done in your/your party's favor. More specifically, it is attached to the verb that **someone else** does **for you**. For example, **マイケルは**(**私に**）ペンを貸してくれた。

もらう is used to describe your party **receiving** an action from **someone else**, using the same example, **私はマイケルに**ペンを貸してもらった。

In the case of ～させてもらう, させて indicates some sort of allowance/permission, and もらう indicates that **you** are the subject that is receiving the permission. Thus, 休ませてもらえますか literally means "Could (you) allow (me) to rest?"